# Maximum value of $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+200}$ over natural numbers

Tags: functions, derivatives

This was a great problem I came across today.Just wanted to share it :-)

$f$ is a function defined over the set of natural numbers(I mean the domain is natural numbers) by
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^3+200}.$$ Then the maximum value of $f$ is ?

Comment: Here's a crappy solution. Consider $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Then $g(x)=(-x^4 - 2x^3 - x^2 + 400x + 200)$ divided by a polynomial with positive coefficients which is hence always positive for x a natural number. Standard methods show that $g$ has two real roots, one negative and one between 6 and 7, so $g$ is positive for $1<=x<=6$ and negative for $x>=7$, meaning $f$ is maximised at 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still used derivatives to find inflection points, and hunt further from there:
$$f'(x^*) = \frac{2x^*({x^*}^3 + 200) - 3{x^*}^4}{({x^*}^3 + 200)^2} = \frac{400x^* - {x^*}^4}{({x^*}^3 + 200)^2} = 0$$
We are interested in when numerator is $0$ and denominator is non-zero, and get
$$x^*\in\{0,\sqrt[3]{400}\}$$
Since $f(0) = 0$, we consider the integers near $\sqrt[3]{400} \approx 7.37$:
$$f(7) = \frac{49}{543} > \frac{64}{712} = f(8)$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the derivative of the given expression, equate it to zero. You will find x is approx. 7.35.  Since we need natural values, a quick check for x = 7 and x = 8 gives the maximum value for x = 7. The max value is approx 0.09

Comment: That is technically insufficient.  $f'(x)=0$ does not necessarily imply $f$ has a global maximum at $x$.  It's not hard to establish it here, though.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this works as long as $f$ has only one maximum, too.

Comment: I agree with both comments, but I thought it was pretty obvious given the nature of f. I was not being completely rigorous, and definitely left holes in the argument, my answer was more an outline on which someone could build